# similar content Project access from a single file

Tags: linux, php, database

I create three different project which are access different three different database.
Except that all project files are same. so, I want that in a project folder all project files and in other two only database connection file. In previous I listen it's possible. How I do this?

Comment: Please don't crosspost without indicating: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25079644/how-to-run-multiple-project-from-a-single-folder-except-configuration-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to look into [symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) I believe.